# Error unicode string, look the same but the essence is not the same

Tags: string, curl, unicode, utf-8

[Eror text unicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1kXD.jpg)

When I use CURL to get the content of a website, the content I get looks the same but the reality is different. This affects the processing and comparison of documents. Is there a way to convert $loi to $check standard form so I can handle it correctly?

You can copy the content $loi or $check into cmd window to immediately see the difference as shown in the picture

```
$loi = 'người được tiêm';
    $check = 'người được tiêm';
    var_dump($loi);
    var_dump($check);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are codepoints that look the same in Unicode in the sense that they have similar or even *identical* graphemes, but are *not* actually the same.

That should come as little surprise when you realise the intent of Unicode is to hold as many languages as possible, and it generally indicates the *purpose* of a letter, rather than the form.

For example `U+2010` and `U+2011` (hyphen and non-breaking hyphemn) are likely to look exactly the same since the latter is simply the non-breaking version of the former.

If you pump your two strings into [the Unicode to code points converter](https://onlineunicodetools.com/convert-unicode-to-code-points), you'll see the difference.

For brevity, I've only done the first word of each, and given the codepoints in hex with square brackets around each "character" :

```
người [6e] [67] [75 31b] [6f 31b 300] [69]
người [6e] [67] [1b0]    [1edd]       [69]
```

For example, the `ư` in the first one is `75 31b`, which is `Latin small letter U` followed by `combining horn` (a modifier to the letter). In the second, it's the single `1b0`, `Latin small letter U with horn` (modifier built in to the codepoint already).

Similarly, `ờ` is `6f 31b 300` in the first, three separate codepoints representing the `Latin small letter O`, a `combining horn` modifier, and a `combining grave accent` modifier. The second has this as `1edd` with both modifiers already incorporated into the single codepoint, `Latin small letter O with horn and grave`.

So, in these cases, it's not actually a different *intent* to the grapheme, but it *is* a different way of representing it, either:

- a single codepoint with modifiers built in; or
- a codepoint with separate *additional* modifier codepoints.

---

If you need to treat them the *same*, Unicode has a concept of [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) and [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization).

Equivalence indicates multiple codepoint sequences that are effectively variants of the same "thing", and normalisation is the process of mapping equivalents to a single variant so that comparison is easier.

In Python, I would use the following to map one way or the other:

```py
import unicodedata
normalised_composed = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', 'người'))
normalised_decomposed = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', 'người'))
# Composed is short sequence (minimal codepoints), decomposed is long.
```

The following transcript shows the outputs, though I've reformatted and annotated for readability:

```py
>>> bytearray('người', 'utf-16')
bytearray(b'\xff\xfe                # Unicode BOM for UTF-16.
    n\x00                           # n.
    g\x00                           # g.
    u\x00 \x1b\x03                  # u, combining horn.
    o\x00 \x1b\x03 \x00\x03         # o, combining horn & grave.
    i\x00                           # i.
')

>>> bytearray(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', 'người'), 'utf-16')
bytearray(b'\xff\xfe                # Identical to previous, it
    n\x00                           #   was already decomposed.
    g\x00
    u\x00 \x1b\x03
    o\x00 \x1b\x03 \x00\x03
    i\x00
')

>>> bytearray(unicodedata.normalize('NFC', 'người'), 'utf-16')
bytearray(b'\xff\xfe                # BOM.
    n\x00                           # n.
    g\x00                           # g.
    \xb0\x01                        # Latin u with horn.
    \xdd\x1e                        # Latin o with horn & grave.
    i\x00                           # i.
')
```

I'm not *entirely* certain what language you're using (there's currently no tag) but, if it claims to handle Unicode, it should hopefully have equivalent functions to do this (hence I still consider this answer useful if you *add* the tag later).

Simply search for `<your_language> unicode normalisation` in your search engine of choice.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, how can I convert $loi to $check so that it can be compared and processed

Comment: @cuongbn: added a chunk at the end to address this.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I use php and I used the Normalizer library in php to normalize strings
`Normalizer::normalize($loi, Normalizer::FORM_C)`